# Is mainline Bitcoin planning on switching to deterministic wallets?

Tags: wallet, backup, deterministic-wallets

Deterministic wallets enable reliable backups but the mainline client doesn't use them.  I was told that bitcoind and Bitcoin-QT are planning on switching to deterministic wallets by default, is this correct?  Any idea of when?

Answer (score 1):

It seems very likely, however it also seems to be a fairly long-term goal with no ETA as of yet: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/5761